# Integrating aweber In codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, aweber

How can I integrate aweber with codeigniter?

Iam new to the aweber. I dont know how it coded?
I alreday integrated mailchimp with codeigniter.
But i dont know aweber integration in codeigniter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the code aweber gives you into a view you want to display it on. There really isn't anything to integrate since all the data processing is done on Aweber's backend.

Comment: when i searched in google for `how to integrate mailchimp with codeigniter` then i get an api and the mailchimp integration with that api is done succesfully .As like If there is any api for aweber that is i meaned by my question.

Comment: A simple google search of "Aweber API" would have given you [the answer](https://github.com/aweber/AWeber-API-PHP-Library).

Comment: but there have a number of files

Answer (score 0):

All the information for Aweber's PHP SDK's are located at

http://labs.aweber.com

Including links to their Github project page with the PHP SDK available for download.

They also include walkthroughs and sample code.

Please note you need to create an account at that url above to use their API.

Answer (score 0):

Open a view of the page where you want to put the aweber subscription form:
Go to: CodeIgniter/application/views/desired_page and open it in a text editor and put form text into it on a desired position (somewhere between  and ).